# match or index data based on given values

Tags: excel, indexing, match

[image: http://i.snag.gy/yALqy.jpg]

I have a pressure value, say 963, and i have a water load value of 4.4. I need to look up the corresponding dew point. The available pressure values, as illustrated, is B2:AJ2. The corresponding water load values are down the column for each pressure value (e.g. for pressure of 900, water load values are at Y4:Y29). Using the given scenario (pressure = 963, water load = 4.4), what formula can I use so that Excel returns the dew point (leftmost column), which is -6?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see your values, but try this:

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$29,MATCH(WaterLoad,OFFSET($A$3:$A$29,,MATCH(Pressure,$B$2:$AJ$2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more precise way to tackle your problem would be a true *reverse-interpolation*.

You'll need some engineering functions to get started (see [Propel](http://propel.codeplex.com)).

First, a two-way cubic interpolation of 'water load' at cell A32 (**Ctrl - Shift - Enter**):

`=interpolate(transpose(interpolate(TABLE, DEWPOINTS, A31, cubic)), PRESSURES, 963, cubic)`, where A31 contains your 'guess' of dew point.

Then, solve for the 'correct' dew point below, where A33 contains *guess - interpolated*, `=A31 - A32`.

`=solveroots(A33,A31)`, which gives the more precise dew point of -6.9.

The benefit is that this method will work with any two-way table.  Using MATCH is tricky if the data is not ordered correctly.

Comment: Thank you, user3589786, but I need the result to match exactly the data that are available on the leftmost column.